# Inspect element in chrome doesnt show any id for the box on the website, how do i find that? code included

Tags: excel, vba, inspect

I'm a noob but trying to get data automatically from my server to excel.
I've managed to select an action block so I have now selected all the data, but now I need to select the export option, but I don't know how to code that because there is no id, please look at the server code below. Thank you so much for any help!

```
Sub LoginToSite()

Const cURL = "my server"

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim UserIDInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate cURL

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set doc = ie.document

Set Box = doc.getElementById("action-toggle")
Box.Click
```

Now what? I'm trying to find the Box that has the two options, of which I want to select "Export selected records to Excel" Please look below at what I found with Chromes inspect element ..

```
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

End Sub
```

Please check image from inspect element from my server, the code isn't formatted here ..

[image: Server]

Comment: ie.document.querySelector("[value='export_selected']").Selected = True  css attribute = value selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: No worries. Did that work? If so, do you mind if I close as duplicate?

Comment: Yes, i used it to select the box and also find download button! Have a nice day